# Конвертация видео в кругляшок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Код:

```py
import telebot

token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❗️ Привет, отправь видео')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def video_id(message):
  document_id = message.video.file_id
  file_info = bot.get_file(document_id)
  print(document_id)
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, document_id)
  bot.send_video_note(message.chat.id, document_id)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Задача: на отправленное видео бот должен отвечать кругляшком телеграма, но он просто отсылает то же видео, в чем проблема?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Если в качестве параметра при отправке указывать `message.video.file_id`, то видео не всегда пересылается кружочком, по этому перед отправкой это видео лучше сохранить, а уже потом отправлять. Выглядит это так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def send_text(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as video:
        video.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.send_video_note(message.chat.id, open('video.mp4', 'rb'))
```

**Так же имейте ввиду, для отправки видео кружком оно должно быть
формата MPEG4, продолжительностью не более 1 минуты и иметь
соотношение сторон 1:1**